# PHP and Security (For the harmful or potential works)

Tags: php, security

I would like to know about what we should consider about the security when we creating a dynamic web page that lot of dealing data between server and client like Facebook, Google+, Paypal etc. We have many malicious works in breking web pages. Like Broken Authentication, Sql Injections, Session hijacking, Cross site scripting attacks.
Therefore PHP has become to more security from step by step with many methods.... I'm just take few examples.

```
//for remove HTML Special characters
mysql_real_escape_string();
strip_tags()
stripshlashes()
/*and mysqli and PDO's prepared statements */

// for prevent Cross site script attacks
htmlspecialchars();
url_encode();
//filter client's data by using
filter_var(); 

//for prevent Session_hijacking attacks
session_regenerate_id()
```

And

Encrypt data by using advanced hash algorithm like AES for protecting data confidential.

Bank and money transaction handling through the SSL(Secure Socket Layer)

Is this methods are only for php security? Is there another? If there is another, what we should consider?

Comment: This is way too broad:  Basic understanding of XSS  and applying it.  Know the difference between validating and escaping. session management, Direct object references, CSRF, Content Security Policy, virus scanners, formatting error messages, X content Type options, safe enumeration, https , authentication methods, anti- rogue crawling, rate limiting. Then some developing things like definition of done, unit testing, continuous integration, TDD, etc.etc. Have fun.

Comment: Use mysqli_real_escape_string instead of mysql_real_escape_string. All mysql_* functions have been removed from Php 7.

Comment: Thanks Nadir Latif and Timmetje!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, this is very broad. Possibly too broad for StackOverflow.

The reason it's too broad is that the security risks you need to deal with are very dependent on *what your software is doing*. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is a tool, often misused, not a must-have solution to security woes.

A long answer would be to start with [a threat model](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications) then consult a [detailed guide](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software) on PHP security.